# Is it good practice to use the same Variable names for both method call and method signature parameters?

Tags: c#

for example:

```
int a;
int b;

int value = getValue(a,b);


private int getValue(int a, int b)
 {

  int value = a+b;
  return value;

 }
```

is the above practical or is it considered to be bad practice and would cause problem later in the development.

Comment: Your example will not compile.

Comment: Could you clarify your problem a little bit?

Comment: There... ummm... *are no* method parameters in your example.

Comment: sorry, added the parameters, as you can see the same variable names are being used in different scopes, i wanted to know if this practice would cause problems...thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realize that it's a contrived example to demonstrate what you're asking, but your example *does* contain a naming problem which I'll point out:

```
int a; // <---- right here
int b; // <---- and here

int value = getValue(a,b); // <--- and a little here

private int getValue(int a, int b)
{
  int value = a+b;
  return value;
}
```

The *problem* isn't in whether or not the variable names match or don't match what they're called in the method.  The *problem* is that the variable names aren't called anything meaningful.  This is considerably more of an issue than what you're asking.

Let's re-factor your method to make the example slightly less contrived...

```
int a;
int b;

int value = GetSum(a,b);

private int GetSum(int firstValue, int secondValue)
{
  return firstValue + secondValue;
}
```

The method is a bit cleaner now and more intuitively reflects its purpose.  Now we re-ask the question... Should `a` and `b` be renamed to match the ones in the method?

Most likely not.  The names in the method have been changed to indicate their context.  The method is getting a sum of two values, the first one and the second one.  So what is the context of `a` and `b`?  Are they also known only as the first one and the second one?  Or do they convey some other meaning that's not readily available?  Something like:

```
int milesToFirstDestination;
int milesToSecondDestination;
```

or:

```
int heightOfPersonInInches;
int heightOfStepstoolInInches;
```

or any other example of two values which would need to be summed for some purpose.  If we added that context to the variable names then we most certainly wouldn't want to add it to the method.  The method should be as general-purpose as possible, performing a single task without any concern outside of that task.

In short, it's neither good nor bad practice, because it's not something to even consider.  There may be times where, by coincidence alone, the names are the same.  (This can often happen with private helper methods, for example.)  But they're not the same as a result of a standard or practice to be followed, but rather as a result of coincidentally having the same meaning.

Comment: @farhad: I'm in the early stages of doing just that, actually :)  If I could describe myself in only one word it would be "excessively verbose."  Indeed, Stack Overflow provides an excellent practice ground for writing.

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean is it a good practice to always name a variable used as the *argument* of a method (at the call site) in the same way as the *parameter* of the method in the method signature? (Your example is unclear, wouldn't compile, and doesn't contain any parameters...)

No - you absolutely don't need to do that. In many cases you're calling a general purpose method which has no clue about your context - but you should name your variables in your calling method in a way which *is* meaningful in that context.

Comment: I think context is a very important word here. People are always looking to make programming practices black or white.

Answer (score 1):

Only in very limited circumstances. Consider, for instance, when you want the minimum of two quantities. In the calling code, you'll know what those two quantities are. But in a general `Min(a,b)` method, it doesn't know or care about what those quantities mean.

---

If it was *generally* true, then each variable name could only be used once in each program. You would no longer *need* parameters to be passed to methods, and every variable would be global (assuming single threaded code).

We try not to write programs like that any more. For starters, it makes writing recursive code a lot less understandable.

Answer (score 1):

> is it good practice to use the same names for both method call and method signature parameters?

I would not have a rule that says you *must* or *should* always do this. First, it presents practical problems. Imagine:

```
private int Square(int n) { return n * n; }
```

What are you going to do here:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int cSquared = Square(a) + Square(b);
```

It's not possible, and it doesn't even make any sense, to give both `a` and `b` the same name, and to use the name `n`. What makes more sense is to give the parameters names that make sense in the context they are being used. So here, thinking of the Pythagorean theorem as `a^2 + b^2  = c^2`, we would use `a` and `b` as the local variable names. But in a different context, another name might make more sense. For example:

```
int length = 17;
int areaOfSquare = Square(length);
```

Again, it makes more sense to use a name that makes sense in the context where the method is being called. Not to use the same name in every context.